# Problemas con curl php

Tags: php, dom, curl

hola amigos estoy haciendo un script php (curl), donde uso DOm para obtener ciertos valores de una WEB (no es mia) luego los voy a enviar por POST a una url de esa web  usando curl.

```
$dom_os = new simple_html_dom();
// Load HTML from a string
$dom_os->load(curl_exec($ch));

$elementos=array();
foreach ($dom_os->find('input[type="checkbox"]') as $element_os) {

    $lote_os=$element_os->value;
    $elementos[] = $lote_os;

}

$resultado = implode(",", $elementos);

echo "asignar=&lote=$lote&orden=&seleccion[]=$resultado&tiporden=0&usuario=0";
```

Listo este código funciona de maravilla, me arma esta estructura con los valores( en negrita) extraidos correctamente de la web externa.

asignar=&lote=202001006318&orden=&seleccion[]=**27062882,27067195,27062258,26877627,27068854,27065635,27070461,27033429**&tiporden=0&usuario=0

Hasta ahí todo bien, luego necesito enviar esa url armada por POST a la web dicha.

Este es el código

```
$url4="https://siprem.co/index.php?opcion=AsociarOrdenes";
$ch4 = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch4, CURLOPT_URL, $url4);
curl_setopt($ch4, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch4, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "asignar=&lote=123&orden=&seleccion[]=**$resultado**&tiporden=0&usuario=0");//$resultado contiene los valores extraidos anteriormente
curl_setopt($ch4, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);//imprime header
curl_setopt($ch4, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);//Almacena en variable
curl_setopt($ch4, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookieFile); // Cookie aware
curl_setopt($ch4, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookieFile);
```

$content4=curl_exec($ch4);

Bien la petición por POST si la hace pero solo cuando se envía un solo valor , por ejemplo:

asignar=&lote=202001007068&orden=&seleccion[]=**27072527**&tiporden=0&usuario=0

pero cuando son varios me sale un error de web service (que maneja la web externa).

Este proceso se realiza manualmente a través de esa web, donde se seleccionan los valores uno o muchos y se envía en un formulario y no hay ningún error del web service. (Intercepté las peticiones que realiza para automatizar ese proceso con PHP.)

No sé que puede estar pasando, si es problema del script o es algún problema del webservice (externo), tal ves si necesita autorización o algo así. (a claro que tengo acceso por medio de credenciales a la web).

---

Hola les muestro el tipo de petición de la web

```
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36 OPR/65.0.3467.62
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3
asignar=&lote=202001005263&orden=&seleccion[]=66582821,66582857,66577624,66574225&tiporden=0&usuario=0
POST: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 09 Jan 2020 21:51:01 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.40-7+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 7304
Keep-Alive: timeout=7, max=9000
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8  
*/
```

Lo que está en negrita es lo que quiero automatizar , es decir obtener los valores (que ya los tengo), y luego realizar el POST , como lo hace la web.
Cuando es un solo valor, por ejemplo **asignar=&lote=202001005263&orden=&seleccion[]=66582821&tiporden=0&usuario=0** ,realiza la acción en la web normalmente, pero cuando son varios sale error de web service en la web, teniendo en cuenta que cuando se hace manualmente dentro de la web con varios valores al tiempo si lo ejecuta, que puede estar pasando?

Comment: Es que este formato: `asignar=&lote=$lote&orden=&seleccion[]=$resultado&tiporden=0&usuario=0` es para mandar por `GET`. Si quieres mandarlo por `POST` tienes que crear un JSON y mandarlo, algo así: **`{
   "asignar":{
      "lote":202001006318,
      "orden":"",
      "seleccion":[
         27062882,
         27067195,
         27062258,
         26877627,
         27068854,
         27065635,
         27070461,
         27033429
      ],
      "tiporden":0,
      "usuario":0
   }
}`** como parámetro de `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`. Prueba con ese mismo objeto a mano.

Comment: El JSON lo puedes crear con `$mJson=json_decode($elementos);` y luego en la petición pones esto: `curl_setopt($ch4, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$mJson);` y listo, se enviarán los datos en forma de JSON. No sé por qué te estabas complicando codificando los datos para un envío del tipo GET. Ah, también tendrías que poner esta opción al cURL: `curl_setopt($ch4, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));`

Comment: @A. Cedano : El tipo/formato del body de un POST se establece con el encabezado `Content-Type` y puede ser -entre otros- `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, no necesariamente JSON. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST).

Comment: Gracias por el dato @sal, realmente lo desconocía. Entonces, ¿vía urlencode se pueden pasar varios grupos de valores, digamos varios registros, varias personas, varias entidades? ¿cómo sería? Habría que ver si el WS admite varias entidades, cómo habría que mandárselas (con qué claves), cómo las lee, etc.

Comment: El PO no quiere enviar varios registros, quiere enviar varios valores de `seleccion`; para la cual sugiero probar con `$resultado = implode('&seleccion[]=', $elementos)`.

Comment: @Sal si lees bien la pregunta se interpreta que quiere enviar varios registros: *« la petición por POST si la hace pero solo cuando se envía un solo valor  ... pero cuando son varios me sale un error de web service »* en cuanto al uso de  `implode`, es mucho mejor crear un JSON a partir del array y enviarlo.

Comment: hola amigos, gracias por sus comentarios, he probado realizar las peticiones con el software POSTMAN, y me da el mismo error  de web service, le he agregado las cookies de la web, no se que más puede ser, autorización o algun procedimiento interno que realiza la web, en fin no sé...